# Hide previous layer after loading fresh layer from Map panel in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to display a layer with coarser resolution to engage the user meanwhile the fine resolution image is getting loaded on the Map panel in GEE. I want this previous layer to get hidden while the new image is loaded completely.
I used following code to display the map

```
Map.addLayer(vector1, {color: 'FF0000'}, "Loading", true, 0.5);
```

After this the final layer with better resolution is created and being loaded, as shown.

```
// Convert to vectors.
var vector = nw.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: water.projection(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false, // it takes4connectedpixels if false
  labelProperty: 'zone',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery()
});
    
// Add area property to dissolved features(non water).
var addArea = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({area: feature.geometry().area(0.1).divide(10e6)});
};
var areaAdded = vector.map(addArea);
///////////////FILTER AREA/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var Area = areaAdded.filter(ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.gte('area', 0.0001),
  ee.Filter.lte('area', 3.5)
));
Map.addLayer(Area,{},"required")
```

after this I want to hide the previous layer by,

```
Map.addLayer(vector1, {color: 'FF0000'}, "Loading", false, 0.5);
```

but this code isn't giving the required output, instead of hiding previous layer it adds the new layer to the map without displaying.
the following is the code for reference.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/ae3ffc87c3f3ffd808210d62adb84615